# The best way to implement controller creation strategies in MVC 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller factory which depending on the route values builds a controller in different ways. These are:

1. If the route values match with a "module" route it determines the correct type using the route values to calculate the qualified type name. This is, if user types [http://localhost:8080/siijyp/modules/**Personas/Naturales/Documento**/Display?id=1], the controller factory builds and returns an OIMSIIJYP.Web.**Personas.Naturales.Documento**Controller
2. If the route values match with a "module" route and it also contains a "script" value, the controller factory builds the controller in runtime using Mono.CSharp
3. If the route values don´t match with a module, it builds the controller as the `DefaultControllerFactory` does it.

It is rather evident all these `if` statements are wrong, I also know there is a `IControllerActivator` type which is used for the `DefaultControllerFactory` to create a controller given a controller type. But what I don´t know is which is the best way to implement these controller creation strategies in MVC 3.

Any idea?

The code:

```
public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, 
    string controllerName)
{
    #region Argument checking
    if (requestContext == null)
{
        throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "ControllerName cannot be null nor empty",     
            "controllerName");
    }
    #endregion
    Type controllerType = null;

    var routeData = requestContext.RouteData;
    if (IsRequestingAModule(routeData))
    {
        var module = routeData.Values["module"];
        var submodule = routeData.Values["submodule"];

        var controllerQualifiedName = string.Format(
            "OIMSIIJYP.Web.{0}.{1}.{2}Controller", module, 
            submodule, controllerName);
        try
        {
            controllerType = Type.GetType(controllerQualifiedName, true, 
                true);
            if (IsRequestingAScriptingBehavior(routeData))
            {
                return GetControllerRuntimeUsingMono(routeData, 
                    controllerName, controllerType);
            }
            else
            {
                return _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
            }
        }
        catch (TypeLoadException)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, 
                string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                "Controller not fount", new object[] {
                    requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path
                }));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var controllerTypes = 
            from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            where StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(
                type.Name, controllerName + "Controller") == 0
            select type;

        switch (controllerTypes.Count())
        {
            case 0:
                throw new HttpException(404, 
                    string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                    "Controller not found", new object[] {
                        requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path
                    }));
            case 1:
                controllerType = controllerTypes.First();
                break;
            default:
                throw UnityControllerFactory.
                CreateAmbiguousControllerException(routeData.Route, 
                    controllerName, controllerTypes.ToList());
        }
    }

    return _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
}
```

Comment: It seems a bit too complicated for my taste.   Can you clarify why you are not using custom routes to handle the specific parameters in your URL?  Most likely you can handle the right controller based on how you define your routes in the global.asax.

Comment: I am doing that because I have controllers with the same name in different modules. This is, there are a lot of controllers called for example: SearchController, ReportController, MasterController, etc. For that reason I use the route values to build the controller qualified name because those controllers are in different namespaces.

Comment: You can still do that if you explicitly define in `global.asax` in the `routes.MapRoute` method, the parameter namespaces in one of the overloaded versions of that method.  


You should probably restate the question with exactly the problem you are trying to resolve.  I still believe that the approach you are taking might not be the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has another workaround, you can use `Area`. Suppose I have two controller same name but stored in two different place one of them inside of area and other is normal, For example

```
admin/Controller/CommonController.cs //here admin is an area name
Controller/CommonController.cs
```

Now i've two Action both are try to render two different view.

```
@Html.Action("SystemInfo", "Common", new { area = "Admin" }) // here Admin is the area name
@Html.Action("HeaderLinks", "Common")
```

the same facility can be obtain using routing.

Comment: This solves one of the problems that we have had. It is too late but good for next project ;) thank you